# Bar Chart Audio Spectograph iOS

Tags: ios, audio, fft, frequency

I'm looking to create an iOS control that will basically display the music players currently playing song information, name, track, time, etc., but also display a Bar chart spectrograph of the different frequencies of the song being played. This is really what I would like as a visualization when I am listening to music on my device. However, I don't see an easy way to get the frequency information. I've looked at the Accelerate framework, but it seems very complicated to use. I really want to make something like an eight level bar chart. lower frequencies indicated on the left, and then higher frequencies on the right.

Does anyone know of a good sample that does something similar? I've seen similar questions asked on stack overflow, and no one seems to have a good answer. There has got to be an easy way to do this. I know there has to be one of you really smart iOS people out there that have found a simple solution that you'd love to share.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this using anything built into iOS.  The "smart people" use advanced audio APIs, and write some real time digital signal processing code.

Comment: There is an example app doing pretty much what you describe as one of the example's in Apple's SDK.  However, if I understand correctly, you want a spectrogram for output of another application?  In which case you're totally out of luck.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking to take the output of the music playing in the music player, or other app that is playing music and process it. The samples that I've seen only process through the microphone of the device.